Getting LastLoggedOnProvider using Win32?
I can get the LastLoggedOnProvider by peeking here in the registry for the correct session:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData
Is there a way to grab the last logged on provider using Win32 given a logon session without having to go to the registry?

probably only via this registry key. and for what is this ?

Just trying to figure out which provider was used

provider only collect user input. not very valuable information

I checked WMI classes but do not find this information. You can use Registry API to get this information like the Win32 provider does.

@RbMm the provider can authenticate.

Can not of course

@RbMm, short of a custom authentication package, is there another way of passing which provider was used to the logon session?

providers not authenticate (and can not). they only serialize user imput and pass to system via ICredentialProviderCredential::GetSerialization the  authentication package is used this data for authenticate. the CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION::clsidCredentialProvider is probably saved under registry . you can read this from registry - in what problem ? despite i not think, that this is very importand and always correct information
